# Operator New in function call

Tags: c++, arguments, new-operator, operator-keyword

```
void F(A* a)
{
    delete a; 
};

F(new A());
```

Will the delete operator release the allocated memory or i must create and delete the object like this:

```
F(A* a) {} 

A a = new A();
F(a);
delete a;
```

Comment: Your second version would result in a double delete.

Comment: @KerrekSB "idiotic" is a bit far. He asked a simple and valid question.

Comment: @Named: I write idiotic code for fun all the time. I'm just careful not to check it into a production system :-)

Comment: Yeah, i know that the second version would result in a double delete but when i was posting the question i was thinking about F() as a different function with no delete in it, my mistake. I fixed my question.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause recursion

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will free memory, but it is preferred to use smart pointers such as [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) prior to C++11 instead. Also in your example it is better to set freed pointer to NULL to avoid double deallocation to [avoiding dangling pointer errors.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Avoiding_dangling_pointer_errors)

```
void F(A*& a)
{
    delete a; 
    a = NULL;
};
```

You will not be able to call it as `F(new A());` thru and will require to pass reference to pointer holding variable. Like in 2nd variant. There should be `A* a = new A();` there thru, to indicate that `a` is a pointer.

Comment: I was about to write same, hence added a link in your answer..but  may be use `void*`

Comment: @KerrekSB Right, added note on that.